# playwright is supposed to start the node server before it tests, inconsistent results

Tags: node.js, playwright

When I run the node server in terminal, then run npx playwright test, the tests pass. When I run tests with this code in playwright.config.ts (and no other server running), I get the following error (inconsistently--sometimes it works!?).

```
webServer: {
command: 'npm start',
port: 3001,
},
```

`Error: Process from config.webServer was not able to start. Exit code: 1`

Comment: Do you know if the port is available for use? have you tried other possible options from https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testconfig#test-config-web-server?

Answer (score 0):

Updated config with `run` should do the trick:

```
webServer: {
command: 'npm run start',
port: 3001,
},
```